# What instagram returns after authorisation? Shows code=

Tags: php, api, authentication, instagram, access-token

I am trying to get access token of logined instagram users. while authorising they returning some code to my redirecting URI, actually what they providing?
the format was like this https://redirect-url.com/?code=
From this how can i get access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the we can get the access token with a small modification in the URL we used to get that code. the URL we used will have a part like response_type=code, just replace it with response_type=token. The result getting in the URl instead of code will be access token

Answer (score 0):

take that CODE and make a POST call like this:

```
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
    -F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
    -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
    -F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
    -F 'code=CODE' \
    https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

you will then get a json response with `access_token`